# Accessing parent scope in nested resource in Rails 3.0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Machine model with a nested resource called Test. The linac has_many tests. The Test model has a boolean attribute called "Baseline". I also have a nested resource called Baselines, which doesn't have a model. It is meant to aggregate all of the most recent tests for that machine for which "Baseline" is set to "True".

In my Machine model, I have a scope called energy_x

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base      
scope :energy_x, lambda { |x| where(:energy => x) }
```

In my Baseline controller, I can successfully access this named scope:

```
      @energies.each do |energy|    
        @baseline_tests << machine.baseline_tests.energy_x(energy)
      end
```

But if I try to access this scope in the view,

```
<%= render :partial => "baseline_test", :collection => @baseline_tests.energy_x(energy)  %>
```

I get a undefined method error:

```
    undefined method `energy_x' for #<Array:0x007f9da7686950>
```

I've heard that I shouldn't be using a scope in a view anyway, but I need a way to sort the collection @baseline_tests according to a parameter. There are unlimited options for the value of this parameter, so it doesn't make sense to create an instance variable in the controller called @baseline_tests_1 and @baseline_tests_2. I think it has to be done in a loop in the view.

Any suggestions?